# Configuring an MDX query on SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssas, mdx, etl

[image]Hi I am having troubles configuring the SSIS task to run an MDX query. 
The parse works fine but it doesn't allow me to display the different columns of the query to map it

Here is the query i used:

```
SELECT [Measures].[# Consumers] ON 0,
      [Company].[Company Country Code].[Company Country Code].MEMBERS ON 1
FROM _CDM
```

The Error thrown is:

> No Column information was returned by the SQL Command

*Error snapshot*

[image]

Comment: before asking your first question is it better to read the [Tour Page](https://www.stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn more on asking good question and other helpful informations, also to get your first `informed` badge

Comment: Hadi, could you please be more precise? His question seems to be good.

Comment: You might need to use Script Component as Source for this. MDX won't run as a SQL Command

Comment: @ArnaudGastelblum take a look at the initial post before my edits. I edited the question to become good :) https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44592041/revisions

Comment: @Cherif what is the connection provider you are using? Oledb provider for analysis services? Or sql server provider?

Comment: Hi Hadi, we're using OleDB for analysis services

Answer (score 7):

You can use MDX Select as a Source in Data Transformation Task.
Two important notes:

- Use **MS OLE DB Provider for Analysis Services**, configure it for your SSAS DB
- In OLE DB Provider for AS, go to *All Properties* Tab, select *Advanced* section and type `Format=Tabular` for *Extended Properties*.

[image: AS OLE DB Data Source]
In this case, at **OLE DB Source Editor** you can input your MDX query.
Important - *Preview* button might not work, you should check query metadata switching to *Columns* tab.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, we're using a multidimensional cube and we have even tried the tabular configuration but it didn't work

Comment: @CherifGhattas, could you share your settings of OLEDB provider for SSAS? And have you tested your query in SSMS - does it return any data?

Comment: Hi Ferdipux, I added the snapshot for the SSAS configuration at the beginning of my post. I confirm we manage to run the MDX query on the SSMS. Thank you

Comment: @CherifGhattas, at your screenshots I do not see `Format=Tabular` among *Extended Properties*. Please set it. Another important point - *Preview* button might not work, after you enter MDX query text, switch to *Columns* tab and check column names there.

Comment: @Fredipux may I wasn' clear but it is a multidimentionnal cube and not TABULAR Thank you

Comment: @CherifGhattas, you have to add configuration parameter `Format=Tabular` for a **multidimensional cube** connection! That is the point.