# How to Link Info Application Studio OLAP CUBE to SSIS? Or Can I convert OLAP DB to MySQL?

Tags: mysql, ssis, olap-cube

I am using Info Application Studio,  a financial reporting system. And the DB it used is an OLAP CUBE.

Recently, I am trying Microsoft Power BI, and trying to link SSIS with OLAP CUBE. But my knowledge had limited this testing of mine.

I would like to seek for advice on how can make the connection possible?
If not, can I convert my OLAP CUBE to MySQL, so it can be read by SSIS.

Please advice guys, thank you.

Comment: Mysql or ms sql server? SSIS and power BI are both MS products.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Configuring an MDX query on SSIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44592041/configuring-an-mdx-query-on-ssis)